# How can I use the instance of KeyVaultManager in Startup.cs ConfigureServices method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, startup

In my startup.cs Configure Services method I would like to configure my KeyVaultManager so that I can use in the same to get the connectionstring to be used by the DB Context. But I have hard time to wrap my head around this to get it to work.

Below I´m getting my connectionstring from the appsettings.json file but I would like to get the value from the keyvault using KeyVaultManager instead. The dependency injection part works fine everywhere in my app, so that part is correctly configured. I just don't understand how I can get hold of it in this method.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAzureClients(azureClientFactoryBuilder =>
        {
            azureClientFactoryBuilder.AddSecretClient(
            Configuration.GetSection("KeyVault"));
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IKeyVaultManager, KeyVaultManager>();

        services.AddDbContext<IApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration
                .GetConnectionString("dbConn"),
                opts => opts.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery)));

        
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```

This is my KeyVaultManager class:

```
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Application.KeyVaultManager
{
    public class KeyVaultManager : IKeyVaultManager
    {
        private readonly SecretClient _secretClient;

        public KeyVaultManager(SecretClient secretClient)
        {
            _secretClient = secretClient;
        }

        public async Task<string> GetSecretAsync(string secretName)
        {
            try
            {
                KeyVaultSecret keyValueSecret = await
                _secretClient.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
                return keyValueSecret.Value;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because of the async nature of accessing the key vault it would conflict with the synchronous delegates used in startup

Comment: just wondering why decided to use you own implementation of IKeyVaultManager instead of Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets;'s AddAzureKeyVault which seems to be more straight forward and easy to use. did you had look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: @CodingMytra that might be an option, but I dont understand how to implement that in my Startup.cs so that I can use it directly in the ConfigureServices method.

Comment: if you are still using program.cs and startup.cs structure then you can have a look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0). it is explained here step by step what needs to be done in program.cs and what needs to be done in startup.cs